# CSS hover transitions doesn't work

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, transition

I'm having problems with getting any form of transition on this hover. I want it to appear a little slower than just abruptly when hovering over it. So maybe just a delay? Or an ease? Anyway I can't seem to get any of these things to work.

```css
.forum-image {
float: left;
width: 75%;
overflow: auto;
position: relative;
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 0.3 ease-in;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3 ease-in;
background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.forum-image:hover .descriptionbox {
visibility: visible;
}

.descriptionbox {
opacity: 0.8;
background-color: #FFF;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="forum-image">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VwTgk9a.png">
    <div class="descriptionbox">
      Testtesttest
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover. Have you tried googling this issue?

Comment: You haven't transitioned the visibility property...and a transition-delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "visibility:hidden" try changing just the opacity, like so:

```
.forum-image:hover .descriptionbox {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

And then put the transition code on the description box:

```
.descriptionbox {
    /* Other properties... */
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0; /* Start opacity at 0, changes when hovered... */
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

Now the description box has the transition property, and when the image is hovered, the new opacity is applied (with the transition time set in the original class). Then that new opacity class is removed when the mouse exits the area.

Make sure you remove

```
visibility: hidden;
```

from the original code, or you'll never see anything! (This messed me up at first when i was trying to fix it)

[Here is a JSfiddle for demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ryav7pq3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.forum-image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.descriptionbox {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.descriptionbox:hover {
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

```html
<div class="forum-image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VwTgk9a.png" />
    <div class="descriptionbox">
        Testtesttest
    </div>
</div>
```